# How to use 0 in variable as a string rather than boolean in || operation?

Tags: arrays, perl, boolean

I have operation of comparison of two variables to choose one that has a value (including 0). The script has to find which of two vars has any value and which does not.

Below is an example:

```
    my @ara = (0,1,,3,4,5);
    my @arb = (1,,3,4,,);
    my $output;
    my $i = 0;
    for (0..@ara) {
       $output .= $ara[$i] || $arb[$i]; # a non-empty value has to be added to the $output.
       $i++;
    }

print $output;
```

output has to be: `013345`

But, Perl deems first element from `@ara` (which is `0`) as a *Nill* (nothing). And thinks the element has **no** value at all. And the real output I have is: `113345`.

The question is: how "*on the fly*" I can convert that `0`s from booleans to strings?

I know, that I could present my `@ara` as below:

```
@ara = ('0', '1', '2'..);
```

But I cannot do that because of some conditions in the whole script.
What I only can do is to convert the exact alone element into needed format (like: `doSomething($ara[$i])`).
I also tried: `$ara[$i]."";` But it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: `$output .= $ara[$i] // $arb[$i]`

Comment: @Borodin, Thank you! God bless you!!!! It works! May I ask you to put your answer and I will vote for it! thanks!

Comment: Having two commas in a row does not create an empty value. You should `use strict; use warnings;`. Also, you cannot use `||` to compare, as that only compares the "truthiness" of the statement. Any value that is not `0`, the empty string, or undefined is true, everything else is false'.

Comment: @TLP, Thanks, I knew all this. That is WHY I am asking the question about an alternative. Cheers.

Comment: Also, the string `"0"` is just as false as the number `0`. Perl is not a hard typed language.

Comment: @An-70 If you know, then why are you asking about it? And why are you using two commas to create empty values if you know it doesn't work? Check for definedness, or use `//` like Borodin said, if being defined is what you consider being a value.

Comment: @TLP: I meant I know NOW))) But I was not sure before I tried. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @An-70 Thanks, I knew all that. (Or did I? ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need the *defined-or* operator, which has been available since v5.10 of Perl

`$x || $y` evaluates to `$x` if `$x` is *true*, otherwise `$y`

In the same way `$x // $y` evaluates to `$x` if `$x` is *defined*, otherwise `$y`

This statement will fix your program

```
$output .= $ara[$i] // $arb[$i]
```

But you should also take note of the other issues that people have raised. In particular, you *must always*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
```

at the start of *every* Perl program you write. That will pick up relatively simple errors that you may otherwise overlook

Comment: Thanks! Use strict and warnings I do everytime! Just reduced the whole size of code for the example. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

There's two ways of doing this:

`defined` which returns true if a variable is defined.

Or the `//` operator, which as of perl 5.10 lets you do something *very similar* to `||` apart from `0` and `''` which would normally be deemed 'false'.

But you don't have to do anything to 'convert' because perl will do that automatically - if you're doing stringy things, it treats `0` as a string, and if you're doing numbery-things it treats `"0"` as a numeric value.

You can either:

```
 $output .= $ara[$i] // $arb[$i];
```

Or:

```
 $output .=  defined $ara[$i] ?  $ara[$i] : $arb[$i];
```

You'll have to use the latter on older versions of perl where `//` isn't available.

Note too though - you've a fencepost error in your for loop. You should probably use:

```
for (0..$#ara) {
```

Because `@ara` in a scalar context returns the number of elements (`5`) - but your indicies are `0` .. `4`.

You should also probably note that:

```
my @ara = (0,1,,3,4,5);
```

Doesn't do what you think it does - the double comma isn't an empty value, it's just ignored.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@ara;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          0,
          1,
          3,
          4,
          5
        ];
```

Maybe you were meaning something more like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ara = ( 0, 1, undef, 3, 4, 5 );
my @arb = ( 1, undef, 3, 4, undef, );

my $output;
for my $index ( 0 .. $#ara ) {
    # a non-empty value has to be added to the $output.
    $output .= $ara[$index] // $arb[$index];  
}

print $output;
```

Comment: If you are using 5.12 or later you can use `keys @ara` instead of `0 .. $#ara`

Answer (score 0):

For Perl 5.10 or higher you can use [logical Defined-Or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator `//` instead of `||`.

```
$output .= $ara[$i] // $arb[$i];
```

For Perl under 5.10 you can use [the conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) `?:`

```
$output .= defined $ara[$i] ? $ara[$i] : $arb[$i];
```

Also let me point some mistakes in your example:

1. Commas collapse in the array definition, use `undef` to add an
   undefined value.
2. `@ara` in the scalar context returns count of elements in the array,
   not the last index. So the `for` loop goes out of range `@ara`.
3. You can assign `$i` inside the `for` loop.

So your example might be like that:

```
my @ara = (0,1,undef,3,4,5);
my @arb = (1,undef,3,4,undef,undef);
my $output;
for my $i (0..$#ara) {
    $output .= $ara[$i] // $arb[$i];
}
print $output;
```